# Mesh Chunk Combining and Extruding

Tags: unity, c#, terrain, mesh, procedural

So I'm working on a proceduraly generated level, that is composed of multiple chunks, so you don't go over the maximum amount of verts allowed in Unity Meshes.
[image: Chunks]
Another function is the ability to raise/lower the mesh to modify it on click.

However, the borders of the chunks break this functionality. And I can't edit both at the same time.
[image: Broken]
Currently to raise/lower, i have a raycast returning the mesh that you are clicking on, and extruding those points. However, this dosen't allow me to edit overlapping boundaries.

Any ideas on a better solution?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could try sphere casting instead to get both meshes. Simply set the sphere cast radius to the radius of your extrusion  brush

Answer (score 1):

Usually people solve this by having an underlying dataset and modifying that, having a border region of extra data in that set around the actual region you want to mesh will solve this as the mesh edges essentially need to be aware of the portion of mesh that is connected to them to line this up right.

Also:

when editing a portion of the data on a meshing edge you should regenerate both meshes.